# Let G be a simple group and let ${n_p}$ be the number of Sylow p-subgroups, where p is prime. Show |G| divides $({n_p})!$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Using this or otherwise, prove groups of order 48 cannot be simple.
could someone help me about this problem? Do we use the Sylow-Theorem?

Comment: The Sylow theorems are only used to know $n_p > 0$. From then on, try to use $G$ to permute some stuff.

Comment: Let $P$ be the set of Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$. This has $n_p$ elements and there is a map $G\longrightarrow {\rm Aut}(P)$ that sends an element $g\in G$ to the automorphism of $P$ that conjugates each $P$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde That was two years ago! I plead not-guilty here. Thanks for closing.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Yes indeed, no problem. There are a couple of classical questions, and somehow they must repeat after a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $P$ be the set of Sylow $p$-groups, for every $g\in G$, define $f(g):P\rightarrow P$ by $f(g)(H)=gHg^{-1}$. This defines a representation $f:G\rightarrow S_{n_p}$. The kernel of this morphism is trivial since $G$ is simple, so $G$ is a subgroup of $S_{n_p}$, apply Lagrange.

For the second part, $48 =2^4\times 3$, take $p=2$, you have by Sylow that $n_p$ divides $3$, but $3!<48$, so $|G|$ does not divide $3!$.

Comment: That's mostly a full solution, not a hint. =/